# "set editing-mode vi" v/s "set -o vi" what is the difference?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

On multiple forums I have come across adding `set -o vi` to my `.bashrc` file. Today I saw the option of adding `set editing-mode vi` to `.inputrc`.

I googled and both appear to do the same thing, are there any key differences between the two?

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310). For the record, the other copy is [on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1815341/432690).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.inputrc` (and `/etc/inputrc`) is the configuration file of the GNU `readline` library. `readline` is developed alongside bash and both are currently maintained by Chet Ramey, but it's also used by many other GNU and non-GNU applications including `gdb`, `python3` or GNU `bc`... Some other shells including `rc` can be configured/built to use readline as their line editor while some others such as tcsh, ksh93, zsh or yash have their own often more advanced line editor.

`bash` also supports changing readline settings for its own line editor via the `bind` command. So you can also do:

```
bind 'set editing-mode vi'
```

`set -o vi` is the Korn shell way to configure the line editor to use `vi`-style key binding. Because the POSIX specification of `sh` is based on the Korn shell, that's also the POSIX `sh` way to configure key bindings there.

And because `bash` intends to be a POSIX compliant shell, it also has a `vi` option set with `set -o` (as opposed to `shopt`) to change the line editor mode to `vi` style (or start `bash` with `bash -o vi`) which in the end does the same thing.

Note that `bash` also gets a lot of features from csh and tcsh. In `tcsh`, you switch between `vi` and `emacs` style of key binding with `bindkey -v` and `bindkey -e`. That is also supported by `zsh`, but not `bash`.

Answer (score 4):

The `.inputrc` settings will take effect in all applications that use `libreadline`, including but not limited to `bash`.

`set -o vi` in `.bashrc` will affect `bash` only.